# Why doesn't Nuketown show up in Black Ops 3?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I recently just purchased Call of Duty: Black Ops 3 with the Nuketown map from Game, but the Nuketown map is nowhere to be found when I play public matches.

Why is this?

Comment: I believe the map shows up only in "chaos moshpit" under the BONUS playlist in multiplayer.  It may show up in some special weekends events as well (previous games have had a 24-7 Nuketown playlist, but I haven't had the game long enough this time around to see it yet).

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife - You should add that is an answer :)

Comment: What console is is this on?

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the game and restart before the map will show up in multiplayer matches after purchasing and installing it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the map shows up only in "chaos moshpit" under the BONUS playlist in multiplayer. It may show up in some special weekends events as well (previous games have had a 24-7 Nuketown playlist, but I haven't had the game long enough this time around to see it yet).

Answer (score 0):

Well you probably did not download it yet if that doesn't work there is a game mode that lets you only play small maps and it will be in there and if it's not there you should reset the game